# On iPad, Select2 creates a weird scrolling behavior on Kendo Grid, anyone, why?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, jquery-select2, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm facing some difficulties, concerning Select2 and Kendo, on iPad, I'll be giving you below .

I have a Select2 component in my Kendo Grid, it works/displays just fine (as you see photo #1 below).

[image]

But as soos as I drag and pull the data goes away and it doesn't come back to initial position (photo #2 below)...

[image]

I'm sure it strongly related to Select2, cuz I tried to replace it to simple select with few options, it works fine.

Thank y'all in advance!

Comment: It happens because of position. When you initialize your scroll, it saves the position where to display popup. Once you move it, it still thinks you on the same place. Try to reinitialize after each drag-n-drop

Comment: Your name sounds like names that come from my homecountry. Its TJK

Comment: Well, could you be more specific, by giving some written examples por favor!

Comment: I forgot to mension that I'm facing this prob on iPad. On PCs, in any browsers, have no difficulties!

Comment: in `select-hidden-accessible` class there's css property called `clip: rect(0 0 0 0)` -------------------- I guess my problem has something to do with that!

Comment: well, if you've fixed, that's good

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution!
If you debug in Chrome's Developper Tools, you'll see that your select has a class called `select2-hidden-accessible`. Inside there's css property called `clip` that simply clips your option. But in iPad it detected my option without showing it.
I simply solved the problem by adding a display property.

```css
.select2-hidden-accessible {
    display: none;
}
```